# Is this a triphase or monophase AC motor?

Tags: motor, ac

I have got this motor from a local junk yard.

**It says it is a monophase motor, but its wiring looks like a triphase one. Please help me classify it.**

It reads

> Monophase dual-value capacitor asynchronous motor
>
> Model ...
>
> Power **2200W**, RPM **2800 r/min**
>
> Voltage **220V**, Frequency **50Hz**
>
> Current **16A**, **B** grade insulation
>
> Operating **45uF/450V**, Starting **300uF/250V**
>
> IP44  Implementing standard: JB/T9542-1999
>
> Serial ..., Date **Aug 2008**
>
> (Left) **CCW**, (Right) **CW**
>
> (Wiring Diagram)

[image: Photo of the motor]

Comment: For reference, we call this kind of motor "split-phase". The 45uF run capacitor shifts the phase to produce a second phase from a single phase supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motor is a single phase motor with an extra winding combined with a capactor to create a rotating field.

This because a single phase motor can not turn by itself. So a rotating field of some kind is required.

The connection diagram is clearly indicated on the id plate.
By placing the shunts on the left side in the vertical sense (U1-Z2 and V1-U2 the motor ccw. Placing them in the horizontal sense (U1 - V1 and Z2-U2) makes the motor cw. 
Since the motor has two capacitors in series ( 300 uF for starting) and 45 for running there should be also a centrifugal switch inside to short out C2 when running

Answer (score 2):

Single phase, as it says.
Phase leads are U1 & U2.

You make connections as per left hand diagram to get clockwise rotation (according to diagram symbol and opposite of text you supplied.)

You make connections as per right hand diagram to get anticlockwise rotation (again, according to diagram symbol and opposite of text you supplied.)

The capacitor values required for C1 and C2 are stamped on the specification plate. These are essential for normal operation.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. There are two power connections: U1 and U2.*

As shown in Figure 1, there are only two power connections. It's single phase.

> Power 2200W, RPM 2800 r/min

It's an induction motor running at less than 3000 RPM, the closest multiple of 50 Hz above 2800.

> Operating 45uF/450V, Starting 300uF/250V

A three phase motor will not require starting capacitors.